# Your development team, 'xxx', does not support the Associated Domains capability

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having trouble with my signing certificate for XCode. The screenshot shows the error:

[image]

Actually, we *have* Associated Domains capability, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your email is enrolled in Apple's $99/year Developer Program.
2. When someone sends you the developer invite from Apple Developer Portal (now in iTunes Connect):
   https://itunesconnect.apple.com/access/users

**Make sure they check this little box for you to access certificates and profiles:** (If they did not, they can go back to the invite and add this permission anytime.)

[image]